# A signalr function is not working in firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I want to redirect on a specific page after file download in `MVC`. And in my application signalr is already configured. So I used following code in controller

```
     var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
     hubContext.Clients.All.RedirectToBatch(BatchID, Convert.ToInt32(Session["AgencyUserID"]));
     return File(stream, "text/plain", (BatchName + "." + ediExtension));
```

And in view I used following code

```
 var chat = $.connection.chatHub;
 chat.client.redirectToBatch = function (BatchID, AgencyUserID) {
                if (currentUserID == AgencyUserID) {
                    var claimlist = $('#ClaimListGrid');
                    if (claimlist.length > 0) {
                        window.location = "/Billing/ClaimSummary/" + BatchID;
                    }
                }
};
$.connection.hub.start().done();
            $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $.connection.hub.start();
                }, 5000); // Restart connection after 5 seconds.
});
```

I think this code will work for redirect to a page after file download. And this works in chrome proper but In firefox this is not working fine.

In firefox following error is occurring

`no element found`

AND

`Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:2804/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=4p2zZ%2B%2F0ok4B9uAxcslDlTv4kpT%2BGbW2nav6S%2Fe5RlSqQgS2gaFr7%2BlQiIrHZu5cPapvjoeZNB8bXM6AeF%2B1b1RS0P6y%2FETaNeAC5hDQkGrwH5xgDfjDHWt%2B%2B52K7yaD&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22chathub%22%7D%5D&tid=10.`

What should I do for this problem?

Comment: It is very likely that your Firewall is blocking Firefox. You need to Allow Firefox access through your Firewall.